# CGContextSaveGState: invalid context 0x0 at App Launch

Tags: ios, xcode, swift, core-graphics, ios9

I have set `CG_CONTEXT_SHOW_BACKTRACE` environnement variable to `YES` because I had a the following error `CGContextSaveGState: invalid context 0x0`.

The following stacktrace didn't help me much.

```
<Error>: CGContextSaveGState: invalid context 0x0. Backtrace:
      <-[UIStatusBarBatteryItemView contentsImage]+773>
       <-[UIStatusBarItemView updateContentsAndWidth]+36>
        <-[UIStatusBarItemView initWithItem:data:actions:style:]+503>
         <+[UIStatusBarItemView createViewForItem:withData:actions:foregroundStyle:]+159>
          <-[UIStatusBarLayoutManager _createViewForItem:withData:actions:]+168>
           <-[UIStatusBarLayoutManager _prepareEnabledItemType:withEnabledItems:withData:actions:itemAppearing:itemDisappearing:]+3
            <-[UIStatusBarLayoutManager prepareEnabledItems:withData:actions:]+108>
             <-[UIStatusBarForegroundView _setStatusBarData:actions:animated:]+951>
              <-[UIStatusBarForegroundView setStatusBarData:actions:animated:]+874>
               <__51-[UIStatusBar _prepareToSetStyle:animation:forced:]_block_invoke+443>
                <+[UIView(Animation) performWithoutAnimation:]+82>
                 <-[UIStatusBar _prepareToSetStyle:animation:forced:]+935>
                  <-[UIStatusBar _requestStyleAttributes:animationParameters:forced:]+404>
                   <-[UIStatusBar requestStyle:animationParameters:forced:]+490>
                    <-[UIStatusBar requestStyle:animated:forced:]+113>
                     <-[UIStatusBar forceUpdateStyleOverrides:]+97>
                      <-[UIStatusBar _evaluateServerRegistration]+294>
                       <-[UIStatusBar didMoveToSuperview]+33>
                        <__45-[UIView(Hierarchy) _postMovedFromSuperview:]_block_invoke+683>
                         <-[UIView(Hierarchy) _postMovedFromSuperview:]+484>
                          <-[UIView(Internal) _addSubview:positioned:relativeTo:]+2305>
                           <-[UIView(Hierarchy) addSubview:]+56>
                            <-[UIStatusBarWindow setStatusBar:]+311>
                             <-[UIApplication _createStatusBarWithRequestedStyle:orientation:hidden:]+384>
                              <-[UIApplication _runWithMainScene:transitionContext:completion:]+1047>
                               <__84-[UIApplication _handleApplicationActivationWithScene:transitionContext:completion:]_block_invo
                                <-[UIApplication workspaceDidEndTransaction:]+163>
                                 <__37-[FBSWorkspace clientEndTransaction:]_block_invoke_2+71>
                                  <__40-[FBSWorkspace _performDelegateCallOut:]_block_invoke+54>
                                   <-[FBSSerialQueue _performNext]+184>
                                    <-[FBSSerialQueue _performNextFromRunLoopSource]+52>
                                     <FBSSerialQueueRunLoopSourceHandler+33>
                                      <__CFRUNLOOP_IS_CALLING_OUT_TO_A_SOURCE0_PERFORM_FUNCTION__+15>
                                       <__CFRunLoopDoSources0+523>
                                        <__CFRunLoopRun+1032>
                                         <CFRunLoopRunSpecific+470>
                                          <CFRunLoopRunInMode+123>
                                           <-[UIApplication _run]+540>
                                            <UIApplicationMain+160>
                                             <main+94>
```

The error is happening at launch and there seems to be a problem with the Battery view. Does this error ring any bell to you ?

FWW my app is mostly written in Swift 2.0, on iOS9 with Xcode 7b6.

Comment: I am having the exact same problem on launch with my app under iOS9 / Xcode 7b6. I'll let you know if I come up with anything.

Comment: Looks like it is general problem when compiling app with xcode 7b6. I am having the same one.

Comment: It's still appearing with Xcode 7 GM.

Comment: I'm getting this too, I was thinking it might have to do with not using storyboards or nibs

Comment: I have this warning too and i am using xibs. I would say its an xcode bug since it does not influence anything just leaves annoying log.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I have encountered the same issue, and the cause of it was, I was playing around with setting different status bar styles for different screens. Therefore and I needed to add "View controller-based status bar appearance" key inside plist. And the warning goes away if I remove this key.

Comment: You got it. I moved to using `    [[UINavigationBar appearance] setBarStyle:UIBarStyleBlack];` to get a status bar with with text.

Answer (score 0):

When you see that error originating in your code, it means you’re passing a `NULL` CGContextRef to some bit of Core Graphics API (in this case `CGContextSaveGState`), which will cause whatever drawing you’re trying to do to not work or to behave unexpectedly.

In this case, it’s not originating in your code, so there’s not much you can do about it—fortunately, the error isn’t fatal, so you can safely ignore it. Might want to [file a bug](https://bugreport.apple.com) with the backtrace, though.